# Django - Slug field for model object not being applied to URL

Tags: python, django

I was watching a YouTube tutorial that showed how to use the id of a model object in the URL of a detailed view of said object, and tried to apply the same concept to the slug field by replacing all 'id' with 'slug' (the name of my model slug field). However this just happens to bring up an error -

> NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/ Reverse for 'campaign-detail' with
>   arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['(?i)dashboard/campaigns/(?P/slug[-\w\d]+)/$']

views.py:

```
def campaign_detail(request, campaignprofile_slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        campaignprofile = get_object_or_404(CampaignProfile, slug=campaignprofile_slug)
        return render(request, 'campaign-detail.html', {'campaignprofile': campaignprofile, 'slug': slug})
    else:
        return redirect('/users/login/next?=')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^campaigns/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.campaign_detail, name='campaign-detail')
```

models.py for the model object I'm trying to display:

```
class CampaignProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name='campaignprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    campaign_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

HTML Template a href tag:

```
<a href='{% url "campaign-detail" slug %}'></a>
```

Any potential solutions for this problem would be amazing thank you.

Comment: So how is `slug` arriving in that last template? What is sending it?

Comment: just a quick tip: instead of checking in every view if the user is logged in just use djangos decorator @login_required...

Comment: @DanielRoseman What do you mean, may I ask? I have since put 'slug' as a variable in my view as 'slug = campaignprofile.slug' in my views.py however this still seems to initiate the same NoReverseMatch error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) The `slug` you are passing in the url in the template seems to be an empty string, and your code in `urls.py` doesn't handle that which causes an error.

2) Once you fix 1, you'll need to make the `slug` variable in the regex of your `urls.py` to have the same name as the second argument in the view function, to prevent an additional error.

Comment: How should the code in the urls handle the template 'slug'?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong variable names in your returned context;

```
return render(request, 'campaign-detail.html', {'campaignprofile': campaignprofile, 'slug': slug})
```

Rename `'slug': slug` to `'slug': campaignprofile_slug`